# Synchronize currently edited file with project view

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How do I sync my project explorer tree-view with the file I'm currently editing? Sort of like Eclipse's Synchronize View. I'm am using Visual Studio 2008/C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `Solution explorer`? It can be done with:

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General -> check `Track Active Item in Solution Explorer`

Answer (score 0):

Try Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General -> Track Active Item in Solution Explorer